# getting null pointer exception on camera set parameters

Tags: android, parameters, nullpointerexception, android-camera

I'm getting an error of a NullPointerException and it is referencing the line Camera.Parameters:

```
    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w,
        int h) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.e(TAG, "surfaceChanged");

        if (mPreviewRunning) {
             mCamera.stopPreview();
             mPreviewRunning = false;
             Log.e(TAG, "stopPeview");
            }
        Camera.Parameters p = mCamera.getParameters();
        Log.e(TAG, "paarameters");

        p.setPreviewSize(w, h);

        mCamera.setParameters(p);  
        Log.e(TAG, " set parameters");
            try {
                mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);

                Log.e(TAG, "setPreview");
                } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            mCamera.startPreview();
            mPreviewRunning = true;
    }
```

Could anyone tell me what the error is in the above code.

I will have to test it again to get the log, but here is the entire code.  I did alter the manifest.

```
public class Picture extends Activity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback{

private String TAG;
private LayoutInflater mInflater = null;
private Camera mCamera;
boolean mPreviewRunning = false;
private SurfaceHolder mSurfaceHolder;
private SurfaceView mSurfaceView;
Button takepicture;
byte[] tempdata;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    setContentView(R.layout.camera_surface);

    mCamera = getCameraInstance (); 

    mSurfaceView = (SurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.surface_camera);
    mSurfaceHolder = mSurfaceView.getHolder();
    mSurfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
    mSurfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);

    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
    View overView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.cameraoverlay, null);
    this.addContentView(overView, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
            LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));

    takepicture = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    takepicture.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View view) {
                mCamera.takePicture(shutterCallback, mPictureCallback,
                jpegCallback);
        }
    });

}

private Camera getCameraInstance() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Camera mCamera = null;
    try {
        mCamera = Camera.open();
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
    return mCamera;
}


ShutterCallback shutterCallback = new ShutterCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onShutter() {}
};
    PictureCallback mPictureCallback = new PictureCallback() {
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera c) {}
};
PictureCallback jpegCallback = new PictureCallback() {
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera c) {
            if(data != null) {
                tempdata=data;
                done();
            }
        }
    };

    void done(){
        Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(tempdata, 0, tempdata.length);
        String url = Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(),
                bm, null, null);        
        bm.recycle();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        if(url!=null) {
            bundle.putString("url", url);

            Intent mIntent = new Intent();
            mIntent.putExtras(bundle);
            setResult(RESULT_OK, mIntent);          
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Picture can not be saved",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        finish();
    }
    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w,
        int h) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.e(TAG, "surfaceChanged");

        if (mPreviewRunning) {
             mCamera.stopPreview();
             mPreviewRunning = false;
             Log.e(TAG, "stopPeview");
            }
        Camera.Parameters p = mCamera.getParameters();
        Log.e(TAG, "paarameters");

        p.setPreviewSize(w, h);

        mCamera.setParameters(p);  
        Log.e(TAG, " set parameters");
            try {
                mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);

                Log.e(TAG, "setPreview");
                } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            mCamera.startPreview();
            mPreviewRunning = true;
    }   

@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    Log.e(TAG, "surfaceCreated");
    try {
    mCamera = Camera.open();
    Log.e(TAG, "camera open");

    } catch(Exception e) {}

    }



@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    Log.e(TAG, "surfaceDestroyed");

    mCamera.stopPreview();  
    mPreviewRunning = false;
    mCamera.release();        // release the camera for other applications
    mCamera = null;

}
}
```

Also, the line the log referenced was the line: Camera.Parameters p = mCamera.getParameters();

Comment: What line is throwing the exception?

Comment: @kmb when you post question here and you have any error or exception always post your full logcat here...because its key to unlock a lock!!!

Comment: would be help full if you paste crash log

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like mCamera is null... did you initialize it? (`mCamera = Camera.open();`)

See the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html) for a checklist as it pertains to taking pictures

Answer (score 2):

Add the below three lines in manifeast file::

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
 <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
 <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
```

To take pictures with this class, use the following steps:

1) Obtain an instance of Camera from open(int).

2) Get existing (default) settings with getParameters().

3) If necessary, modify the returned Camera.Parameters object and call 
setParameters(Camera.Parameters).

4) If desired, call setDisplayOrientation(int).

5) Important: Pass a fully initialized SurfaceHolder to setPreviewDisplay(SurfaceHolder). Without a surface, the camera will be unable to start the preview.

6) Important: Call startPreview() to start updating the preview surface. Preview must be started before you can take a picture.

7) When you want, call takePicture(Camera.ShutterCallback, Camera.PictureCallback, Camera.PictureCallback, Camera.PictureCallback) to capture a photo. Wait for the callbacks to provide the actual image data.

8) After taking a picture, preview display will have stopped. To take more photos, call startPreview() again first.

9) Call stopPreview() to stop updating the preview surface.

10) Important: Call release() to release the camera for use by other applications. Applications should release the camera immediately in onPause() (and re-open() it in onResume()).

Comment: Here is the the code to initialize the camera:   private Camera getCameraInstance() {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  Camera mCamera = null;
  try {
   mCamera = Camera.open();
  } catch (Exception e) {
   
  }
  return mCamera;
 }

Answer (score 1):

There are many solutions, but this is an easy, dead cheap option that worked for me:

```
try{
   mCamera.autoFocus(autoFocusCB); //Or whatever part of code that crashes
   }
catch(Exception e){
   Log.v("joshtag","THIS PHONE DOES NOT SUPPORT AUTOFOCUS!!"); //a warning, popup, whatever
   }
```

Voilà! Trap deactivated.

Of course, dont forget the manifest permissions....

Comment: This seem to did the trick for me. for me i had set focus mode to `Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE` which was working for some devices and not for others. Then i changed it to `Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_AUTO` and voila the code was buttery smooth